# Allow app unpinning with pin even with device ownership set to this app

Tags: java, android

I am setting device ownership for my app using dpm command (dpm set-device-admin) and in my MainActivity.java I have placed the code below :

```
DevicePolicyManager myDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    // get this app package name
    ComponentName mDPM = new ComponentName(this, MyAdmin.class);

    if (myDevicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(this.getPackageName())) {
        // get this app package name
        String[] packages = {this.getPackageName()};
        // mDPM is the admin package, and allow the specified packages to lock task
        myDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(mDPM, packages);
        startLockTask();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to auto pin - not device owner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Whenever my app starts it auto pins itself, making it unable for users to leave. Without setting device ownership I am able to leave 'pinned' state by long pressing back button and providing the pin.

When I set the ownership this actions is overrided - all I see is 'App is pinned : unpinning isn't allowed on this device'. Is there any way to enable unpinning by providing pin as without device ownership? I still need it to make sure it autopins without any prompts.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible answer:**

Override single/long key press, request pin and unpin app on success

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(null, null);
   if (intent != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CONFIRM_DEVICE_CREDENTIALS);
   }
  }
 }


 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CONFIRM_DEVICE_CREDENTIALS) {
   // unpin the app
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    stopLockTask();
   } else {
    // nope
    Toast.makeText(this, "Pin is not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  }
 }
```